# Hosted app: “Installation of this item may not work properly”

Tags: google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store, hosted-app

[My hosted app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/importkalkulator/gbedoekflkgigddflbffiloekmogopif?hl=en&gl=NO) is showing a floating banner with a notice saying “Installation of this item may not work properly.” on its Google Chrome Web Store product page. The app is undiscoverable by [searching the Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/importkalkulator?hl=en&gl=NO).

What is causing this problem? I find no additional information in the developer dashboard.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue for my extension. I've seen this question pop up on the [chrome apps](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!forum/chromium-apps) google group several times, and no clear reason is given for why this happens.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Does it just go away?

Comment: @PaulDraper, it has not resolved itself for me in two months. So it is not likely to just resolve itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you get this message, it is probable that there really is an error in the manifest or locale files (For example, in my case it was a trailing comma on the locale files).

The process y follow to solve the problem was:

1. Try to instal the app version you have just submited to the chrome store. When you try to install the app you will probably get a error message thats points you on the track of the problem of your manifest file.
2. Solved the problem on the app and upload it again. You may get the same error on the developers panel. Two thinghs can be appening:

   A) If you've already corrected all errors in the manifest files remenber to publish the changes and what is more important remenber that the publication process may take a few minutes to become effective. The message will disappear after a while if everything is okay. (This explains why is you look on the internet for that problem you find people saying that the message will disappear after a while)

   B) If error persist event after the publishing process have been complete finished. You may have not solved all error on the manifest file go back to Step 1

cheers

Comment: No error in the console or anywhere else i can locate when installing. No problem with manifest or locale files. Triple checked everything.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem. When I tried installing, I got an error message about a missing file.

When I removed my locales directory, everything worked fine.

Comment: I do not have a locales directory at all.